# Python 2.7.17 error: SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument

Tags: python-2.7

I made this code in PYTHON 2.7.17:

```
class prt(object):
    def _print(self, x):
        self.x = x
        print x
    def Write_turtle(self, shape, move=False, text_of_show, font=('Arial', 16, 'bold')):
        try:
            x.shape(shape)
            x.write(text_of_show, move, font)
        except:
            from turtle import *
            x = Turtle()
            x.shape(shape)
            x.write(text_of_show, move, font)
```

And it gave me this error at the end of line 5:

```
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

Can anyone help me?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python function arguments with default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54490349/python-function-arguments-with-default-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your definition of `Write_turtle` the parameters `move` and `font` have 
default parameters. As the error message tells you, you have to put them 
at the end of the parameter list, e.g.:

`def Write_turtle(self, shape, text_of_show, move=False, font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'))`

The reason is, that these parameters are optional. If you do not set them, the default value is used. Because `text_of_show` has no default parameter, you always have to set it. This also implies, that you have to give all parameters before it a value. Therefore the default value for `move` is obsolete. If you call e.g.

`Write_turtle((20, 10), True)`

the interpreter would not know if the `True` is the value for `move` or for `text_of_show`. If you rearrange the parameters correctly as mentioned above you can call:

```
Write_turtle((20, 10), True)
Write_turtle((20, 10), False, True)
```

The first version sets `move=False` (its default value) the second one sets `move=True`.

[For more information have a look at this!](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-arguments-in-python/)

Comment: Thanks, but now I recive this error:
SyntaxError: import * only allowed at module level (<pyshell#244>, line 6)

Comment: Now the problem is in the line: `from turtle import *` You should replace the `*` by the methods you really need. `import *` is only allowed at "top" level of your file structure. Another solution could be to move `from turtle import *` to the top of your file. [Have a look at this post!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571514/python-why-should-from-module-import-be-prohibited)